# .NET Core Publish Task Slow after upgrading blazor project to .Net 7

Tags: azure-pipelines, blazor-webassembly, azure-pipelines-build-task, .net-7.0

Azure Pipeline '.Net Core Publish' task too slow after upgrading the project to Dot Net 7.

It just took less than 8 min before, using Dot Net6. After the upgrade to dot net 7 it takes more than 50 min and most of the times it fails if it doesnt complete withing 60 mins

Project Type: Blazor WebAssembly DotNet hosted

**Framework:  .NET 7**

**Agent: windows-latest (Also tried in ubuntu-latest)**

[image]

**Yaml for publish step:**

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘BuildConfiguration’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/Server/Agfund.Server.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

**optimizing file assemblies is too slow**

[image]

Comment: Refrence of **Microsoft.Graph version 5** causes the issue.

Slowness is while Optimizing assemblies for size.

Comment: I have the same problem, Blazor publish takes around 23 minutes, slowness while Optimizing assemblies for size

Comment: Have you found a fix for this? Does adding a trimmer assembly root to Microsoft Graph work?

Comment: Looks like this is being tracked here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1702

Comment: I have the same problem, but I am not using Microsoft.Graph.  All of my blazor projects take 5-10 minutes to build, and all the time is in this optimize step.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a work around/hack for now, but if you use [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs) in azure pipelines you can set the `timoutInMinutes` property to something like 200 mins.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: build_blazor_ui
  timeoutInMinutes: 200
```

This does not fix the root issue, but will prevent the azure pipeline from timing out.